# How to filter ArchUnit rules by ArchTag programatically?

Tags: java, junit5, archunit

I want to customize a shared ArchUnit library containing a bunch of ArchRules by excluding some optional rules on the using side. The library looks like this

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.acme")
class ArchUnitTestLibrary {
    @ArchTag("optional")
    @ArchTest
    static final ArchRule optional_rule = classes().that()....;

    @ArchTest
    static final ArchRule mandatory_rule = classes().that()....;
}
```

and the using specific tests look like this:

```java
@AnalyzeClasses(packages = "com.acme")
class ArchUnitTest {
    @ArchTest
    static final ArchTests includedRules = ArchTests.in(ArchUnitTestLibrary.class);
}
```

Is it possible to exclude the rules tagged with "optional" programmatically? I know that I could instruct the maven runner to exclude tags but I would prefer to keep the integration and execution simple for the users of the library.